# Need concept while rotating the images in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am implementing the rotation one at a time using jquery. I have some images I want to rotate one at a time using maybe "touchmove", or "swipeleft" or "swiperight".

First, I make a background where I can place my all images. My problem is that can I give a static value (top left) in starting and change the top and left value on swipeleft and swiperight event.

This is what I want to achieve:
[image: Screenshot of browser with circular pane]

My code:

```
<body>

<div class="outer-container">


</div>
</body>

.outer-container{
background-image: url(images/dial.png);
width: 400px;
height: 403px;
background-size: cover;
top: 280px;
left: 32%;
position: absolute;
}
```

This is what it looks like right now:

[image: Screenshot of browser with circular pane without buttons]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For adding new images:
Just put a bunch of these: `<img src="--path--" style="position:absolute;top:--value--;left:--value--;" id="--uniqueID--"></img>` and replace --path-- with the path to the image and --value-- with the appropriate positions. Also replace --uniqueID-- with a unique ID (no two pictures should have the same ID).

I'm not completely sure what you're asking, but you can include a stylesheet in your page to set initial `top` and `left` values, and then use jQuery's .css() to dynamically change those values.

```
$('.outer-container').on('swipeleft',function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#--uniqueID--').css("left",newLeftValue);
      $('#--uniqueID--').css("top",newTopValue);
});
```

replace --uniqueID-- with the picture you want to move.

Replacing newLeftValue and newTopValue with appropriate values.

See http://api.jquery.com/css/ for more information on jQuery's css method.

Comment: So you don't understand my question..!!

Comment: Please check my updates..till now I am able to add only background image.Now I am asking to place images statically contant value(top ,left)

Comment: So you want `<img>` tags style with `top` and `left`?

Comment: yes ..I don't know to implement this so that it look like the same thing

Comment: can you use fiddle and use my images make a demo like want I want ?

Comment: Sorry, this is all very basic HTML. You can look at the HTML and CSS references at w3schools for more information. <img> tags are for placing images in a document: <img src="path to image"></img>

Comment: Just put a bunch of these: `<img src="--path--" style="position:absolute;top:--value--;left:--value--;"></img>` and replace --path-- with the path to the image and --value-- with the appropriate positions.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36852/discussion-between-user1542984-and-mdenton8)